# Model Binding Multiselect in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, multi-select

My Class is

```
public partial class Reference
    {    
        public Reference()
        {
          this.Reference1 = new HashSet<Reference>();         
        }
        public int[] Permissions{ get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Reference> Reference1 { get; set; }
        public int RefID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

and view is

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @model Trials.Classes.Reference
       <table>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2">        
             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RefID, @ViewBag.role as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdown" })
          </td>    
          <tr>    
          <td colspan="2">          
             @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Permissions,
                        @ViewBag.permissions as MultiSelectList,
                        new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Choose Permissions...", style = "width:500px;", tabindex = "4" }
               )

           </td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"  /></td>
            <td> <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="closeDialog()" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
}
```

and controller is

```
public ActionResult editPermissions(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.role = new SelectList(rep.getRoles("Roles"), "RefID", "Description");
            ViewBag.permissions = new SelectList(rep.getRoles("Perms"), "RefID", "Description");
           Reference r = db.Reference.Find(id);
          r.Permissions = r.Reference1.Select(rf => rf.RefID).ToArray();
            if (r == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                    return PartialView("_editRole", r);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the multiselect list doesnt shows the values coming from db. This fisr dropdown shows the value coming from datbase as preselected but in multidropdown it just shows empty.... I want to show preselected values which are already in that object and then user can deselect or select more as well....
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

MultiSelectList takes a parameter to indicate the selected values and you are not supplying this. However, the code as written will work with a normal SelectList, which is derived from MultiSelectList anyway. Therefore just remove `as MultiSelectList` from the view.

If there's a reason I'm missing that this has to be a MultiSelectList then you will need to set up the selected items in your controller. You could do this by getting current values from the database first and then set up ViewBag.permissions. This would look something like:

```
public ActionResult editPermissions(int id)
{
    ViewBag.role = new SelectList(rep.getRoles("Roles"), "RefID", "Description");
    Reference r = db.Reference.Find(id);
    if (r == null) return HttpNotFound();
    r.Permissions = r.Reference1.Select(rf => rf.RefID).ToArray();
    ViewBag.permissions = new MultiSelectList(rep.getRoles("Perms"), "RefID", "Description", r.Permissions);
    return PartialView("_editRole", r);
}
```

Note also that at present you set a value on r before checking for null. Therefore you will have a null reference exception before hitting your null check. I've re-ordered your method to fix this as well as set up the selected values.

Comment: Thank you Andy....Thanks it worked...I was missing the argument in Multiselect....